# hive's regexserde: something is wrong with my regex and I don't know what

Tags: regex, hive

I'm still getting null for the values...

the regex for the pattern string space string space date space string till end of line

```
([^ ]*)\s([^ ]*)\s(\[[0-9][0-9]\/[A-Za-z]{3}\/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \+0000\])\s(.*$)
```

the type of line it is supposed to match (randomly generated line)

```
filesystem af68ccf949ebc07c250b37a10fa40912 [20/Aug/2013:19:00:11 +0000] fbec6e8ec3fa6687426f8437cdd8593f346081ca1978057a
```

It seems to be right on http://rubular.com/

The create table:

```
CREATE TABLE example1 ( 
 user STRING,
 bucket STRING,
 date STRING,
 rest STRING )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "input.regex" = "([^ ]*)\s([^ ]*)\s(\[[0-9][0-9]\/[A-Za-z]{3}\/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \+0000\])\s(.*$)",
 "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Still don't know why my regex didn't work but this seems to work

```
([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]* \+[^ ]*)[^ ]* (.*)
```